# Does Spring's autowire attribute in XML override how @Autowired property of the bean is autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

It seems not the case. I used to have the notion that XML configurations are meant to override annotations. But when I set autowire="no" in the XML configuration, the bean's @Autowired annotated property still takes effect. I'm no longer sure if XML autowire has anything to do with @Autowired anymore. It's quite counter-intuitive in my opinion.

Can someone point me to a documentation that says something about this?

Here's my example:

```
<bean class="com.example.Tester"></bean>
<bean class="com.example.ClassToTest" autowire="no"></bean>

public class Tester
{
    @Autowired
    ClassToTest testSubject;
}

public class ClassToTest
{
    @Autowired // I want this not to get autowired without removing this annotation
    private OtherDependency;
}
```

Comment: @arikg Yes, I intend to do it for my test cases.

Comment: then I think you need to have a look at this open issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6050

Comment: Show your bean class and configuration. You are probably defining another bean, not overriding your original one.

Comment: @arikg I just saw that. That is unfortunate. Maybe that's really it; it can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

autowire="no"  means we have to explicit wire our dependencies using either  XML-based configuration  or `@Autowire`  and it is default setting.
Auto-wiring by xml configutaion or by annotation means implicitly mapping dependencies using given strategy.
For more details refer [here](http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-autowiring.html)

Comment: So does that mean setting the autowire in XML does not override the annotations? If you think of it, it actually makes sense. @Autowire does not allow us to specify the autowiring strategy so maybe `@Autowire` has a totally different intention from autowire in XML. It's just quite counter-intuitive. I'll accept this as an answer. Your second sentence is vague, but your first sentence is more accurate.